# AWS application load balancer listener rule paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Configuring an application load balancer.

I have 3 separate target groups and about 30 different paths I'd like to filter on.

When filling out `path pattern` what are the possible values? Given it's called "pattern" gives the impression it can accept regex but validation is preventing this.

Is it possible to match multiple paths to a target group or will I have to create a separate rule for each path?

I realise using an additional level in my paths (ie /group1/path, /group2/path) would simplify this but looking at if there's an easy solution for current architecture I've inherited.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I realise this is 2 months old but I have been looking at this today and I found the existing answer not very useful.

There doesn't appear to be support for full usage of regex, instead [only the * and ? characters are used for regex matching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html). You can't use any of the characters outside of the supported range as shown below:

- A-Z, a-z, 0-9
- _ - . $ / ~ " ' @ : +
- & (using `&amp;`)
- * (matches 0 or more characters)
- ? (matches exactly 1 character)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-rule.html#options

From my experience you are forced to create separate rules for each path-pattern if you want to do more complicated matching.

---

Edit:

As part of some [new changes to ALBs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) you can now have <strike>75</strike> 100 rules per ALB not including defaults. You can also route by host header which is cool.

Comment: I found the same thing and AWS support actually confirmed when I lodged a ticket with them :P thank you for following up though!

Comment: You probably meant "& (using &amp;)"

Comment: @JoeSadoski this was a really long time ago but when I check the link it does seem like you're correct so I updated my answer. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Have you found any information that indicates how to define "not path pattern", e.g. "any path but `/bad/*`", without adding multiple rules?