# Terraform Regex in Route

Tags: terraform

I'm creating an `aws_lb_listener_rule` containing a condition that matches on path-pattern that validates part of the route for a UUID.

Right now, the route is `/company/\\[0-9a-fA-F-]{36}`, but the terraform run gives this error:

`Condition value "/company/\[0-9a-fA-F-]{36}" contains a character that is not valid`

Does anyone know the proper syntax to embed my regex here? I'm unsure given that the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener_rule.html) only use `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Path Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions):

> A path pattern is case-sensitive, can be up to 128 characters in length, and can contain any of the following characters.
>
> - `A–Z`, `a–z`, `0–9`
> - `. $ / ~ " ' @ : +`
> - `&` (using `&amp;`)
> - `*` (matches 0 or more characters)
> - `?` (matches exactly 1 character)

So unfortunately there is no support for more complex path patterns or regular expressions by default.

see also [AWS application load balancer listener rule paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658775/aws-application-load-balancer-listener-rule-paths)